# C# Select equivalent of javascript map

Tags: javascript, c#

Just trying to see if C# select has the same capabilities like javascript map or not (doing some computations and then returning at the end).

For example:

```
const numberList = [1,2,3,4,5];
const newNumberList = numberList.map(number => {
  const modifiedNumber = number * 2;
  return modifiedNumber;
})
```

Yes, in this example, I can just do number => number * 2. But I am wondering for more complex scenarios where I need to do some function calls to figure out some values and then make use of them and return a list at the end.

Comment: By "more complex scenarios" do you mean "doing more than one statement in the anonymous method body passed as the argument to Select"?

Comment: https://brunoscopelliti.com/blog/csharp-linq-equivalents-of-javascript-array-methods/

Answer (score 6):

You've got three options, one of which you've already pointed out.

One - single statement lambda

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] newNumbers = numbers.Select(x => x * 2).ToArray();
```

Two - multi-statement lambda

```
int[] newNumbers = numbers
    .Select(x => {
        var newVal = x * 2;
        return newVal;
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Three - use an actual method (rather than anonymous method)

```
private static int MultByTwo(int val)
{
    return val * 2;
}

// ...

int[] newNumbers = numbers.Select(MultByTwo).ToArray();
```

Note, you don't write `MultByTwo()`, it's just the name of the method.

Comment: ah yes. exactly what I was after. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Select` is the equivalent of `map`. Indeed, LINQ is a functional interface over `IEnumerable<T>` just like the JS implementation on arrays. The signature is:

`IEnumerable<T> => (T => R) => IEnumerable<R>`

As long as you adhere to the `Select` [contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))) you can write more complex code that calls functions that call other functions and so on.